# Newtonsoft.Json: Use Dictionary<string, List<string>> as content value for JProperty

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using the `Newtonsoft.Json` package and want to add a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` as the content parameter to a `JProperty`.

For this I created the following sample code

```
    try {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> fields = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            {
                "foo",
                new List<string>() { "a", "b" }
            },
            {
                "bar",
                new List<string>() { "c", "d" }
            }
        };
        
        new JProperty(nameof(fields), fields);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
```

I also created a playground for reproduction

https://dotnetfiddle.net/OjyJ5u

Unfortunately I get this exception

> System.ArgumentException: Could not determine JSON object type for
> type
> System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]].
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.GetValueType(Nullable`1 current, Object
> value)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue..ctor(Object value)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.CreateFromContent(Object content)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object
> content, Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object
> content, Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.Add(Object content)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray..ctor(Object content)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty..ctor(String name, Object content)
> at Program.Main()

Does someone know what's wrong with the code?

If that's not possible, are there any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create `JToken` from `fields` to serialize it, by using [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) like :

```
JProperty property = new JProperty(nameof(fields), JToken.FromObject(fields));
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` to `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`

You could serilaize if you just need the json string:

```cs
public static void Main()
    {
        try {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> fields = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
            {
                {
                    "foo",
                    new List<string>() { "a", "b" }
                },
                {
                    "bar",
                    new List<string>() { "c", "d" }
                }
            };
            
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

You could use dynamics if you want a JObject:

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        try {           
            dynamic fields = new JObject();
            fields["foo"] = new JArray("a", "b");
            fields["bar"] = new JArray("c", "d");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```